# Scatter-Like Operation in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am faced with the following problem:

I have a numpy array `A` of shape `(*S, N, N)` where `S` is an arbitrary tuple and `N` is some positive integer. Another array `I` of shape `(*S, 2)` represents indices in `A`. The values in `I` are integers in `{0, ..., N-1}`.

I would like to set

`A[i1, ...., ik, I[i1, ..., ik, 0], I[i1, ...., ik, 1]] := 0` (Pseudocode)

for all valid indices `i1, ..., ik`.

For instance, consider the following example where `N=3` and `S=(2)`:

```
A = np.array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
               [ 4,  5,  6],
               [ 7,  8,  9]],

              [[10, 11, 12],
               [13, 14, 15],
               [16, 17, 18]]])

I = np.array([[0, 2],
              [2, 1]])
```

The desired output in this case would be

```
np.array([[[ 1,  2,  0],
           [ 4,  5,  6],
           [ 7,  8,  9]],

          [[10, 11, 12],
           [13, 14, 15],
           [16, 0, 18]]])
```

Note that the 3 at index `(0, 0, 2)` (corresponding to the value `I[0]` being `np.array([0, 2])`) and the 17 at index `(1, 2, 1)` (corresponding to the value `I[1]` being `np.array([2, 1])`) were changed to 0.

This looks a little like the scatter operation in PyTorch. However, it doesn't exactly match that problem. Additionally, numpy doesn't provide a scatter method. I have worked through numpy's documentation on indexing and a variety of methods to distribute values. Nonetheless, I haven't managed to come up with a clever approach to solve this problem (i.e. one without loops).

I would be grateful for suggestions!

Comment: Could you provide a small example with an `A` and `I` and the desired output? :)

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen I have updated my question. One should keep in mind that the situation could be much more complicated if `S` is a general tuple ;)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting problem!

I believe you can simply reshape `A` and `I` to `(-1,N,N)` and `(-1,2)` respectively and always handle the problem in `(K x N x N)`, then simply `reshape` back to to original dimension. My proposed solution is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# Just extend the problem a little because why not
A = np.array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
               [ 4,  5,  6],
               [ 7,  8,  9]],

              [[10, 11, 12],
               [13, 14, 15],
               [16, 17, 18]],
            
              [[19, 20, 21],
               [22, 23, 24],
               [25, 26, 27]],
])

I = np.array([[0, 2],
              [2, 1],
              [1, 1]])


B = np.stack([A,A])
C = np.array([
    [[0,2],
     [2,1],
     [1,1]],
    
    [[0,0],
     [1,1],
     [2,2]],
])

def scatterlike(A: np.ndarray, I: np.ndarray, target: float=0):
    A_ = A.copy().reshape(-1, *A.shape[-2:])
    A_[(range(len(A_)),*I.reshape(-1,2).T.tolist())] = target
    return A_.reshape(A.shape)
```

I did a `A.copy()` in the code as it made it easier to debug, but you can do everything in place if you'd like. I am pretty sure this code works for `(*S, N, M)` as well, which is nice. I avoid indexing using `np.ndarray` types since the indexing behavior is different for `np.ndarray` and other iterables.

Here are some outputs:

```
# Simplest case  
scatterlike(A[0], I[0])
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

# Extended version of the example you (OP) provided
scatterlike(A, I)
array([[[ 1,  2,  0],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16,  0, 18]],

       [[19, 20, 21],
        [22,  0, 24],
        [25, 26, 27]]])

# Higher dimensions, B.shape is (2,3,3,3)
scatterlike(B, C)
array([[[[ 1,  2,  0],
         [ 4,  5,  6],
         [ 7,  8,  9]],

        [[10, 11, 12],
         [13, 14, 15],
         [16,  0, 18]],

        [[19, 20, 21],
         [22,  0, 24],
         [25, 26, 27]]],


       [[[ 0,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6],
         [ 7,  8,  9]],

        [[10, 11, 12],
         [13,  0, 15],
         [16, 17, 18]],

        [[19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24],
         [25, 26,  0]]]])

# Even higher dimensions, B[None].repeat(2,0) is of shape (2,2,3,3,3)
# Output should be like above but repeated
scatterlike(B[None].repeat(2,0), C[None].repeat(2,0))
array([[[[[ 1,  2,  0],
          [ 4,  5,  6],
          [ 7,  8,  9]],

         [[10, 11, 12],
          [13, 14, 15],
          [16,  0, 18]],

         [[19, 20, 21],
          [22,  0, 24],
          [25, 26, 27]]],


        [[[ 0,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5,  6],
          [ 7,  8,  9]],

         [[10, 11, 12],
          [13,  0, 15],
          [16, 17, 18]],

         [[19, 20, 21],
          [22, 23, 24],
          [25, 26,  0]]]],



       [[[[ 1,  2,  0],
          [ 4,  5,  6],
          [ 7,  8,  9]],

         [[10, 11, 12],
          [13, 14, 15],
          [16,  0, 18]],

         [[19, 20, 21],
          [22,  0, 24],
          [25, 26, 27]]],


        [[[ 0,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5,  6],
          [ 7,  8,  9]],

         [[10, 11, 12],
          [13,  0, 15],
          [16, 17, 18]],

         [[19, 20, 21],
          [22, 23, 24],
          [25, 26,  0]]]]])
```

## Bonus

Just for fun, I think you can even turn the function to work for `(*S,*G)` (by getting the shape information from `I`) as well, that is, instead of only 2D arrays of shape `(N x N)`, you can have like `(N x M x L x ...)`. Also you could specify what each target value should be:

```
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike
from typing import Union
def scatterlike_general(A: np.ndarray, I: np.ndarray, target: Union[ArrayLike,float] = 0):
    A_ = A.reshape(-1, *A.shape[-I.shape[-1]:])
    A_[(range(len(A_)),*I.reshape(-1,I.shape[-1]).T.tolist())] = target
    return A_.reshape(A.shape)
```

It should be noted that I have not tested `scatterlike_general`, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dimensions of A represented by S using a flattened mesh grid.
To access the appropriate locations in I, you can use the same flattened mesh grid.
He's some code that implements this idea.
[image]

Here's an additional more complex example (sorry for not including the whole array A at the output):
[image]

Comment: Hello! I just wanted to give you a heads up: it is preferred in stackoverflow that you post code as actual text using backticks rather than using screenshots. It makes it more challenging for people to employ your code as people cannot copy paste.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm sorry, I'm just use to as a T.A. not give code as text to my students. I'll have to embrace a new methodology here.

Comment: No problem! Dont worry about it, nevertheless, you spent some of your free time contributing to the community :)